# Given positive rational numbers t, r, s where t < rs, how to construct positive rational numbers p, q such that t = pq and p < r and q < s.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove Theorem 1.7.10 (3.c) of The Real Numbers and Real Analysis which is

```
let r,s ∈ ℚ, then i(rs)=i(r)i(s)
```

where i is the function embeds ℚ to ℝ of dedekind cut.

I have already proved most part of the theorem but the proof depends on the following lemma.
$$∀t,r,s ∈ ℚ⁺, t < rs → ∃p,q ∈ ℚ⁺, t = pq ∧ p < r ∧ q < s$$

Comment: Well you have a typo. At the end you should have $t<rs$ (as in title).

Comment: Sorry, typo fixed

Answer (score 1):

We have $\frac t s <r$. The interval $(\frac t  s,r)$ contains a rational number $p$. Let $q=\frac t p$. I will let you verify that $p$ and $q$ have the desired properties.

Comment: Thank you so much. Didn't expect there would be anwser so quickly.